# how to reduce list chart to one and use select dropdown to show selection without refresh page?

Tags: javascript, html, django, chart.js

I am a beginner learning to make charts with pandas converted in json format.
I have a lot of graph against the data, but it takes a lot of space; so i would like to know how can i make a filter and only display what the user want to see.
I read some tutorial that made with dropdowns with html,
but the problem is that I have to do this dynamically and depending on the size of the data,
do you have any suggestions for the process?

```
var trend_axe = {{trend_axe | safe}};
for (i in trend_axe){
    var item = JSON.parse(trend_axe[i]);
    var label = [];
    for (j in item){
     label.push(item[j].date_);

    }
    var stock = [];
    for (k in item){
     stock.push(item[k].stock);

    }
    new Chart(document.getElementById(item[i].axe),{
        type :'line',
        data :{
                  labels: label,
                  datasets: [{
                    label: 'Trend journalier des ventes',
                    data: stock,
                    fill: false,
                    borderColor: '#0E9036',
                    tension: 0.1

                  }]
        },
    });
};
```

what i could do :

```
<div class="chart">
    <canvas id="MDVS1"></canvas>
    <canvas id="MDV03"></canvas>
    <canvas id="MDV01"></canvas>
    <canvas id="MDV04"></canvas>
</div>
```

[edited]
trend_axe is like this but it varies depending on the data

```
['[{"axe":"MDVS1","date_":"2021-06-28","stock":0},{"axe":"MDVS1","date_":"2021-06-21","stock":0}]'
  '[{"axe":"MDV03","date_":"2021-06-18","stock":2},{"axe":"MDV03","date_":"2021-06-21","stock":2}]',
  '[{"axe":"MDV02","date_":"2020-11-28","stock":3},{"axe":"MDV02","date_":"2020-11-30","stock":2}]',
  '[{"axe":"MDV01","date_":"2021-01-21","stock":1},{"axe":"MDV01","date_":"2020-10-14","stock":1}]'
]
```

Comment: Can you show content of your json ?

Comment: @Swati of course! it's edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first generate options with `axe` and `i` values then whenever any option is selected get that index value and use `JSON.parse(trend_axe[el])` this will give the *JSON Array* at that index and simply generate your chart . Also , i have use only one chart container so you need to *destroy* previous chart then *redraw* new chart on same container.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var trend_axe = ['[{"axe":"MDVS1","date_":"2021-06-28","stock":0},{"axe":"MDVS1","date_":"2021-06-21","stock":1},{"axe":"MDVS1","date_":"2021-06-22","stock":3}]',
  '[{"axe":"MDV03","date_":"2021-06-18","stock":2},{"axe":"MDV03","date_":"2021-06-21","stock":1},{"axe":"MDV03","date_":"2021-06-23","stock":3}]',
  '[{"axe":"MDV02","date_":"2020-11-28","stock":3},{"axe":"MDV02","date_":"2020-11-30","stock":2}]',
  '[{"axe":"MDV04","date_":"2021-01-21","stock":3},{"axe":"MDV04","date_":"2020-10-14","stock":1}]'
] // {{trend_axe | safe}}
//generate option using json from server
var html = `<option value="">Select</option>`
for (i in trend_axe) {
  var item = JSON.parse(trend_axe[i]);
  //set value as index...[{}]
  html += `<option value="${i}">${item[0].axe}</option>`
};
document.getElementById("all_data").innerHTML = html
var chart;

function generate_chart(el) {
  if (chart) {
    chart.destroy(); //destroy previous chart
  }
  //not first option
  if (el != "") {
    var item = JSON.parse(trend_axe[el]);
    var label = [];
    for (j in item) {
      label.push(item[j].date_);

    }
    var stock = [];
    for (k in item) {
      stock.push(item[k].stock);

    }
    //generate chart
    chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: label,
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Trend journalier des ventes',
          data: stock,
          fill: false,
          borderColor: '#0E9036',
          tension: 0.1

        }]
      },
    });

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.0/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-JxJpoAvmomz0MbIgw9mx+zZJLEvC6hIgQ6NcpFhVmbK1Uh5WynnRTTSGv3BTZMNBpPbocmdSJfldgV5lVnPtIw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<select id="all_data" onchange="generate_chart(this.value)"></select>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you, the word destroy graph escaped me!
what if i want to display all the graphs in this container and use axis as a label to make filters?
because in my first code it just overwrites the graph.
Thank you

Comment: let's say i would like something like this https://jsbin.com/yafacaxuli/edit?js,output

Comment: Hi, but date are different what about them ?

Comment: the data is the same but instead of the select filter we simply use the axis label,
basically displays all the graphs in a single container and it is the label at the top that will do the filter on which to display

Comment: Yes we can do that as well .. But in that example if you see these `Barcode Sticker Problem..` are same in that json arrays for all . But, according to your json `date` is different for all not same so it will become complicated but, if you have date same or make empty date if there is no entry on that date then we can easily achieve that .

Comment: Hi Swati, would you know what is my problem here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282921/how-to-group-duplicate-labels-in-order-to-create-a-label-without-duplicates-in-c