# how to group duplicate labels in order to create a label without duplicates in chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts

I can't seem to solve this problem:
my label sends me back lists,
I would like in my case here to have only HOME40, HOME60 and PRO as label, but unfortunately it returns the concatenation of that,
I would also like to change color, if the product is HOME40 then the color must be green, if PRO then red.
anyone have any suggestions?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="trendmensuel">
    <canvas id="trendmensuel"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
       var trendMensuel = [ 
  { produit: "HOME40Z", mois: "Janvier", effectif: 6, bgColor: "red" },
  { produit: "HOME60", mois: "Janvier", effectif: 7, bgColor: "green" },

  { produit: "HOME40Z", mois: "Février", effectif: 6, bgColor: "red" },
  { produit: "PRO", mois: "Fevrier", effectif: 9, bgColor: "blue" },

  { produit: "HOME60", mois: "Mars", effectif: 3, bgColor: "green" },
];


   var label_trendMensuel = trendMensuel.map(function(e){
    return e.mois;
   });

   var produit_trendMensuel = trendMensuel.map(function(e){
    return e.produit;
   });

   var effectif_trendMensuel = trendMensuel.map(function(e){
    return e.effectif;
   });;

var ctx = document.getElementById("trendmensuel");
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type :"bar",
   data : {
     labels : label_trendMensuel, // ito efa mety
     datasets:[
     {
        type: "bar",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
        borderColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
        borderWidth: 1,
        label: produit_trendMensuel,
        data: effectif_trendMensuel,
     },],
   },

   });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
var trendMensuel = [
  { produit: "HOME40Z", mois: "Janvier", effectif: 6, bgColor: "red" },
  { produit: "HOME60", mois: "Janvier", effectif: 7, bgColor: "green" },
  { produit: "PRO", mois: "Janvier", effectif: 9, bgColor: "blue" },
  { produit: "HOME40Z", mois: "Février", effectif: 3, bgColor: "red" },
  { produit: "HOME60", mois: "Février", effectif: 4, bgColor: "green" },
  { produit: "PRO", mois: "Février", effectif: 1, bgColor: "blue" },
];

const data = trendMensuel.reduce(
  (a, b) => {
    const i = a.months.findIndex(x => x === b.mois);
    const j = a.products.findIndex(y => y.label === b.produit);

    if (i === -1) {
      a.months.push(b.mois);
    }

    if (j === -1) {
      a.products.push({
        type: "bar",
        backgroundColor: b.bgColor,
        borderColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
        borderWidth: 1,
        label: b.produit,
        data: [b.effectif],
      });
    } else {
      a.products[j].data.push(b.effectif);
    }

    return a;
  },
  { months: [], products: [] }
);

var ctx = document.getElementById("trendmensuel").getContext("2d");
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: data.months, // ito efa mety
    datasets: data.products,
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.4.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="trendmensuel" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: if you try with this data i edited you will get 3 more labels, but i don't want to have more labels when more data comes in

Comment: @SarindraTherese, I update my answer for your latest data. Hope it helps

Comment: yes that's what i want,
and will you know a way how can i stack this graph?

Comment: @SarindraTherese, good to hear. For stacking a graph. you can have a look of this example. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/stacked.html

Comment: hey, there is a problem, if there is missing data the graph shifts,
No matter how much I tried but I can't figure out how to fix it, @ikhvs I will edit the data

Comment: @SarindraTherese, Can you please open another question for this? The questions should be focusing on one issue instead of changing every time. I am happy to help, please let me know after you open a new question.

Comment: yesss! [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68300410/part-2-how-to-group-duplicate-labels-in-order-to-create-a-label-without-duplic]

Comment: @SarindraTherese, Thanks for your reply. I will have a look tmr.